# Joomla 2.5 super administrator can't edit front end

Tags: joomla2.5

I m login in the frontend with a super-administrator user (only super-admin box tips on the backend user parameters), but there isn't any little editing icon displayed near articles. Is there a trick somewhere in the backend that could block frontend edition?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to resolve.

I replaced the folder "article" in my custom template
/templates/templatename/html/com_content/article

I copy/pasted the original "article" files from one of Joomla's
templates that come with install ( I used beez5)
There are two files in that folder (the path given above) and they include:
default.php
index.html