# Joomla: how to insert frontend edit icon in template?

Tags: templates, joomla, edit, frontend, joomla2.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Joomla 2.5 super administrator can't edit front end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301399/joomla-2-5-super-administrator-cant-edit-front-end)

I did install a template (not a joomla native one) that doesn't diplay the frontend icon.

Any idea where and how I could put it? If I knew I would copy past the code needed from a native joomla template. How would it look like? Just a link with some php? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did to resolve.

I replaced the folder "article" in my custom template
/templates/templatename/html/com_content/article

I copy/pasted the original "article" files from one of Joomla's
templates (beez5) that come with install 
There are two files in that folder (the path given above) and they include:
default.php
index.html

Answer (score 2):

Well this depends if you are using K2 or Joomla Article Manager to display the articles. What you need is not code for the template itself.

If you are using K2 you will need to create a new user group in the K2 component, add your username to it, then give the use group editing permissions.

If you are using the default Joomla one, go to:

Joomla Bakcned >> Article Manager >> Options >> Editing Layout tab

Then ensure the first 2 parameters are set to "Yes".